# linux nfs issue

Tags: linux, centos

I am trying to mount a directory from Linux (named roshan. version centos 5) to solaris (named orchid version solaris 8). I did the following:

```
[root@roshan /]# cat /etc/exports
/backup2 *(sync,rw,no_root_squash)
/share_to_orichid orchid(sync,rw,no_root_squash)

[root@roshan /]# exportfs -a
```

As you see I shared the directory from Linux. Now I am going to mount it from Solaris

```
bash-2.05# mount roshan:/share_to_orchid /mount_from_roshan/
Permission denied
```

well. problem shows up. Permission denied.
And I try another way.

```
[root@roshan /]# exportfs -o rw,no_root_squash orchid:/share_to_orchid/
[root@roshan /]#
```

now mount from Solaris again it will succeed

```
bash-2.05# mount roshan:/share_to_orchid /mount_from_roshan/
bash-2.05# cd /mount_from_roshan/
```

So my question is why the first way failed. Is there any difference between the first and second way?

Comment: There is a typo of "orichid" in your described /etc/exports.  Just checking that this isn't the problem.

Comment: hmm how to mark this answer as a correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, just to list this as an answer, then:  There is a typo of "orichid" in your described `/etc/exports` file.

Note also that the `showmount` command can be helpful in checking the exports of a remote machine.  In this case, from the Solaris machine orchid, you could run

```
showmount -e roshan
```

to see what roshan is exporting, and to where.  My tests show that `exportfs` will happily export non-existent directories without complaint, but you may at least notice such a typo while checking.